# Why are my images getting smaller and smaller?

Tags: vba, powerpoint

Here's some VBA code that allows users to replace multiple images/pictures at once, based on whats selected. Works perfectly, other than if you keep replacing the image, it gets smaller each time you do it. I can't find a way to have the new images live in the same dimensions as the original, but keep their aspect ratio and not look distorted.

Is there a way to do this? It works natively if you right click and press replace picture - it' always the right size/same size as the original.

````
Sub ChangePicture()
    Dim sh As Shape
    Dim t As Single, l As Single, h As Single, w As Single
    Dim newShape As Shape
    Dim filePath As String
    Dim fileDialog As fileDialog
    
    ' Create a FileDialog object to open the file picker dialog
    Set fileDialog = Application.fileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
    
    ' Allow only image file types
    fileDialog.Filters.Add "Images", "*.jpg; *.jpeg; *.png; *.bmp; *.gif"
    
    ' Display the file picker dialog and check if the user selected a file
    If fileDialog.Show = -1 Then
        ' Get the selected file path
        filePath = fileDialog.SelectedItems(1)
        
        ' Loop through each selected shape in the active window
        For Each sh In ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange
            ' Check if the selected shape is a picture
            If sh.Type = msoPicture Then
                ' Capture properties of the selected picture such as location, size, and rotation
                With sh
                    t = .Top
                    l = .Left
                    h = .Height
                    w = .Width
                    Rotation = .Rotation
                End With
                
                ' Delete the selected picture shape
                sh.Delete
                
                ' Add a new picture shape with the desired properties
                Set newShape = ActiveWindow.Selection.SlideRange.Shapes.AddPicture(filePath, msoFalse, msoTrue, l, t, -1, -1)
                
                ' Resize the new picture shape while preserving aspect ratio
                If newShape.Width / newShape.Height > w / h Then
                    newShape.Width = w
                    newShape.LockAspectRatio = msoTrue
                Else
                    newShape.Height = h
                    newShape.LockAspectRatio = msoTrue
                End If
                
                ' Apply the rotation angle to the new picture shape
                newShape.Rotation = Rotation
            End If
        Next sh
    End If
End Sub
```
````

Comment: The image gets smaller or the filedialog? (I've had com objects shrink on every click, totally randomly, in excel years ago and there was never a solution to it besides deleting the workbook and starting over. Very annoying).

Comment: have you tried locking the aspect ratio before resetting the Width/Height?  Also, I would make `newShape.Width / newShape.Height`and `w / h` as variables before comparing them.

Comment: "I can't find a way to have the new images live in the same dimensions as the original, but keep their aspect ratio and not look distorted." That's the issue. If the new image has a different aspect ratio, it _will_ have different dimensions. That's just how images work. If you take a closer look at the right-click Change Picture utility, it does _not_ maintain the same dimensions. It keeps the width and changes the height. You code has to do the same.

Answer (score 0):

I found this code, which works:

```
Sub ChangePictures()
    Dim sh As Shape
    Dim t As Single, l As Single, h As Single, w As Single
    Dim newShape As Shape
    Dim filePath As String
    Dim fileDialog As fileDialog
    
    
    
    
        ' Create a FileDialog object to open the file picker dialog
        Set fileDialog = Application.fileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
        
        ' Allow only image file types
        fileDialog.Filters.Add "Images", "*.jpg; *.jpeg; *.png; *.bmp; *.gif"
        
            ' Check if any shapes are selected
    If ActiveWindow.Selection.Type = ppSelectionShapes Then
        
        ' Display the file picker dialog and check if the user selected a file
        If fileDialog.Show = -1 Then
            ' Get the selected file path
            filePath = fileDialog.SelectedItems(1)
            
            ' Loop through each selected shape in the active window
            For Each sh In ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange
                ' Check if the selected shape is a picture
                If sh.Type = msoPicture Then
                    ' Capture properties of the selected picture such as location, size, and rotation
                    With sh
                        t = .Top
                        l = .Left
                        h = .Height
                        w = .Width
                        Rotation = .Rotation
                    End With
                    
                    ' Delete the selected picture shape
                    sh.Delete
                    
                    ' Add a new picture shape with the desired properties
                    Set newShape = ActiveWindow.Selection.SlideRange.Shapes.AddPicture(filePath, msoFalse, msoTrue, l, t, -1, -1)
                    
                    ' Resize the new picture shape while preserving aspect ratio
                    Dim originalAspectRatio As Double
                    Dim newWidth As Single
                    Dim newHeight As Single
                    
                    ' Calculate the aspect ratio of the original image
                    originalAspectRatio = w / h
                    
                    ' Calculate the new dimensions while maintaining aspect ratio
                    If originalAspectRatio > 1 Then
                        ' Original image is wider
                        newWidth = w
                        newHeight = w / originalAspectRatio
                    Else
                        ' Original image is taller or square
                        newWidth = h * originalAspectRatio
                        newHeight = h
                    End If
                    
                    ' Set the dimensions and aspect ratio lock of the new picture shape
                    With newShape
                        .LockAspectRatio = msoTrue
                        .Width = newWidth
                        .Height = newHeight
                    End With
                    
                    ' Apply the rotation angle to the new picture shape
                    newShape.Rotation = Rotation
                End If
            Next sh
        End If
    Else
        MsgBox "No images selected. Please select at least one image.", vbExclamation + vbOKOnly, "Error"
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: `originalAspectRatio` as double is not consistent with the other variables as singles, and there would not be the need of so many digits anyway.